# Display user's post on a new ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I'm working on an app that let's users post, like and comment, so as part of my comment implementation, I'm trying to display the user's post, so you are able to comment on it. I am using a UITableView that is the main timeline and it displays all of the posts users have made, so what I'm trying to do is that when a user clicks on a cell, it displays the post of that cell so you are able to comment on it, but I'm having trouble displaying it.

This is the code that I have for that implementation so far, so what am I missing?
Is there anything else that I can do to be able to display the selected post in a viewController after the user clicks on the cell?

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class DetailViewContoller: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var postLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var commentTableView: UITableView!

var post: PFObject?
var commentView: UITextView?
var footerView: UIView?
var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0

var comments: [String]?
let FOOTERHEIGHT : CGFloat = 50;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    commentTableView.delegate = self

    /* Setup the keyboard notifications */
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

    if(post?.objectForKey("comments") != nil) {
        comments = post?.objectForKey("comments") as? [String]
    }

    println(post)
    println(post?.objectForKey("content"))
    self.postLabel.text = post?.objectForKey("content") as? String
}


func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    var info:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    var keyboardHeight:CGFloat =  keyboardSize.height - 40


    var animationDuration:CGFloat = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! CGFloat

    var contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardHeight, 0.0);
    self.commentTableView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.commentTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

}

func keyBoardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    self.commentTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    self.commentTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let count = comments?.count {
        return count
    }
    return 0
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = commentTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentTableViewCell
    cell.commentLabel?.text = comments![indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if self.footerView != nil {
        return self.footerView!.bounds.height
    }
    return FOOTERHEIGHT
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: commentTableView.bounds.width, height: FOOTERHEIGHT))
    footerView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 243.0/255, green: 243.0/255, blue: 243.0/255, alpha: 1)
    commentView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: commentTableView.bounds.width - 80 , height: 40))
    commentView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    commentView?.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)
    commentView?.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    commentView?.scrollsToTop = false

    footerView?.addSubview(commentView!)
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: commentTableView.bounds.width - 65, y: 10, width: 60 , height: 30))
    button.setTitle("Reply", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:  0/0.0, green: 179/255.0, blue: 204/255.0, alpha: 100.0/100.0)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.addTarget(self, action: "reply", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    footerView?.addSubview(button)
    commentView?.delegate = self
    return footerView
}


//Hide keyboard after touching background
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

//remaining characters
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool{

    if (text == "\n") {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    return true
}

func reply() {
    post?.addObject(commentView!.text, forKey: "comments")
    post?.saveInBackground()
    if let tmpText = commentView?.text {
        comments?.append(tmpText)
    }
    commentView?.text = ""
    println(comments?.count)
    self.commentView?.resignFirstResponder()
    self.commentTableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

Comment: So what's wrong with this code? What doesn't work?

Comment: @rocky it doesn't display the post you click on a new viewController and it's not adding the comments to the post

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in your code that actually fires when you click on a table cell. The way I would modify your code is to:

1. Implement `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {}`
2. Use `indexpath` to determine the object you want to display detail for
3. Create a new viewcontroller for the detail, pass the object to it and then push it

A more elegant (but complex, in some ways) way of doing things is to implement `PFQueryTableViewController` and then use the function `objectAtIndexPath()` to retrieve the relevant object and display detail

Comment: I just have a siege that when you click on the cell it'll redirect you there. I didn't write any code for it, just ctrl drag the cell to the view controller. 
I am not using a `PFQueryTableViewController`, but I can use an implemented method I have for the `objectAtIndexPath()`, but since I have no code for the siege, is that a crucial part to display the post in a view controller?